# How do you model big web forms in an MVC-based web app?

Tags: model-view-controller, forms, model

I'm talking about HUGE forms - like medical forms with 1000+ fields.

How do you logically create models for them? Do you include every single little field as seperate model? Do you have the whole form as a HUGE model with every single field? Do you have formsections as models and each formsection has few fields?

I know this might be subjective, but I really want some advice on someone who has dealt with this before and save others a lot of time down the road by avoiding mistakes at the onset.

Answer (score 1):

Your data model should follow an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) method. Medical systems are well suited to this approach as not all patients are going to have all this information filled in. This method allows you to fill in what is appropriate and populate your model. Makes organizing the data easier as well.

As for organizing it in the view, I suggest you break it up into sections where sections are logically related to each other (past history, family history or by type of information), making the information easier to digest.

Comment: Interesting. I can see how this is good approach. However, we're already using XML to deal with the varying information for each form. For the models, I'm not sure how I'd use this? For example if I have 'participants' field in the form, I want the 'participants' model to inherit from the 'persons' model, etc.

Comment: hmm, not sure how you'd set it up with XML. We use this pattern with Zend. There are hierarchies and the keys are known so the child models will always have access to parent keys as well.

Comment: I think what you're referring to is a model to store web form data in a database. I wanted to know how about models in your application. How do you get the logically define classes that get this data and do something meaningful with it?

Comment: You mean how do you make meaningful use of all the data and keep it stored in your class? We use PHP's magic methods (__set/__get) and a few utility methods to get at the data. So you don't need to define member variables for fields which you have no idea will be available or not for an entity. So on load we load up all the related data from the EAV table and when the model is called `$model->SOMEKEY` we check whether that's there in the data we loaded up send it out